# Reference Paths and Nuget

Tags: path, reference, nuget

I want to override a nuget package reference to a dll using the Reference Paths setting in Visual Studio. This does not seem to work.

So as of now, I remove the nuget package and add the reference as a dll. But this seems like a lot just when you can override DLL's by using the Reference Paths setting.

Shouldn't Reference Paths setting just as well override nuget package refs? Or am I missing something?

Comment: what "Reference Paths setting in Visual Studio"? Do you mean HintPath in your csproj?

Comment: @zivkan Right-click project, go to Properties. Then on the left side (tabs), you should find 'Reference Paths' .. these allow you to override the locations of dll's.

Comment: to anyone investigating, this only exists for traditional project files, not SDK style projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Works for me"

Here's how I tested. Note, as I wrote in a comment to the question, the project property page "Reference Paths" only exists for traditional projects, not SDK style projects.

I created a console app, added the `Dapper` and `Newtonsoft.Json` packages using `packages.config`, and changed my `program.cs` to this:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReferencePathTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new List<int>() { Dapper.DbString.DefaultLength };
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, my program outputs `[4000]`.

Next, I created a class library named `Dapper`, changed the `AssemblyReference.cs` file to set both version numbers to `1.60.0.0`, then changed the c# file to:

```cs
namespace Dapper
{
    public class DbString
    {
        public static int DefaultLength => -1;
    }
}
```

I also created another class library named `Newtonsoft.Json`, changed the assembly version to `12.0.0.0` and changed the c# file contents to:

```cs
namespace Newtonsoft.Json
{
    public class JsonConvert
    {
        public string SerializeObject(object o)
        {
            return "i'm a hacker";
        }
    }
}
```

Compile the two classlibs, copy the assemblies to a directory, then add that directory to the list of reference paths. Rebuild the console app and run it, and now I see `[-1]`. So, why did my custom dapper.dll get used, but not my custom newtonsoft.json?

Open the Developer Command Prompt, cd to your console app directory and run `msbuild -bl -t:rebuild`, then open `msbuild.binlog` in the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/). I searched for the full path to one of the dlls in my reference path, and I found it in the results of the `ResolveAssemblyReference` task. Expanding some interesting nodes in the tree, this is what I see:

[image: screenshot showing dapper.dll was selected from reference path, but newtonsoft.json was considered and rejected, before selecting the nuget package version of the DLL]

So, we can see that it selected my dapper.dll, and it considered my newtonsoft.json.dll, but the full message was cut short. Copying it to the clipboard and pasting it in a text editor, I can see the full message:

```
Considered "C:\Users\zivkan\source\repos\ReferencePathTest\ReferencePathTest\..\ReferencePath\Newtonsoft.Json.dll",
            but its name "Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            didn't match the expected name "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed".
```

Ok, so Newtonsoft.Json.dll from the NuGet package is strong name signed, whereas Dapper.dll is not, but how does the compiler know?  Well, look at your csproj:

```xml
    <Reference Include="Dapper, Version=1.60.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Dapper.1.60.6\lib\net451\Dapper.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

So, when you installed the package, NuGet did asset selection, then told the project system to add references to your csproj, using the assembly full name. Since Dapper.dll isn't strong name signed, we can trivially create a custom Dapper.dll that either the compiler or the runtime uses instead of the one from the package. However, since Newtonsoft.Json.dll is strong name signed, the only way I can trick the compiler or runtime to load my custom version is if I can create a certificate where the public key matches Newtonsoft.Json's real public key, and then sign my custom dll with that cert.

At the top of my answer, you might have noticed that I wrote I added package references to my console app using `packages.config`. This is important because if you use `PackageReference` instead, the .NET build targets and tasks doesn't do assembly resolving in the same way and doesn't use reference paths.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I was using packageReference and so it didn't do the binding resolution I expected.Thanks.